# Is there a formula to populate a Column Header (Question) & Cell (Answer) under that Column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not super well versed in excel so I don't know the correct terminology. But is there a formula that can do this with a "|" in between each question and answer?

[image]

I've just been doing this manually and it's obviously not very efficient.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! I'll have to keep building upon this! 

If blank, I was just going to substitute it was "N/A". I'm assuming I can just add that in between the two quotation marks.

I'd love to understand this a little bit better. In your formula where you have [@[When should we follow up?].. does this mean if i'm looking at my sheet, the very last column header should kick off the start of my formula?

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping to grasp the full concept of the formula. I've added another screenshot under my original post "enter image description here". 

These are all the Column Headers. It ends at Column AI. Do you know how I can build upon what you've built to extend all the way to Column AI?

Thank you!

Comment: These are the Column Header Names:

AI = Rating: 
AH = Notes: 
AG = List other type of laboratory: 
AF = Please select the type of laboratory that most closely matches yours: 
AE = How many beds are in your coordinated care network? 
AC = Are you a decision maker? 
AB = What is your primary job function? 
AA = Timeline for purchase: 
Z = List Panel(s) of Interest:
Y = List other product(s):
X = Product area(s) of interest? (Multiple choice):
W = When should we follow up?
V =  How should we follow up? (Select all that apply):
U =  Are you a current customer?

Comment: Output data would look like this in one cell T2 (Column Name Description2):

Are you a current customer? Yes |  How should we follow up? (Select all that apply): Have salesperson call | When should we follow up? < 1 Week | Product area(s) of interest? (Multiple choice): N/A | List Panel(s) of Interest: Joint Infection | Timeline for purchase: Immediate need | What is your primary job function? Lab Director / Assistant Director | List other job function(s): N/A | Are you a decision-maker? Yes |  .... Last column Header is AI. Blank cells are N/A

Comment: It looks like great for the entire row 2! But, if I added info or text into row 3, the formula in cell T2, T3, T4, etc. show up as #CALC! . Does it do that on your end?

Looks like in Google Sheets I can copy the formula down and it works for the entire row, but when I do the same in Excel it comes back with that #CALC!

Comment: See i have updated in my answers, instead of using the structured references, i have specifically used the cell reference.

Comment: That worked! Thank you Mayukh! I tried to upvote as well, but it says my account is too new.

Comment: Question has been answered!

Comment: Sounds Nice. Good luck with your work =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this using `Ampersand` i.e. `&`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>S2</kbd>

```
=IF(
    [@[When should we follow up?]] =
        "",
    "",
    Questiontbl[[#Headers],[How should we follow up? (Select all that apply)]] &
        " " &
        [@[How should we follow up? (Select all that apply)]] &
        " | " &
        Questiontbl[[#Headers],[When should we follow up?]] &
        " " &
        [@[When should we follow up?]]
)
```

---

The above formula uses `Structured references` to concatenate with the cell values, however if you want to use cell references without `Structured references` then you may try this as well

```
=IF([@[When should we follow up?]]="","",$V$1&" "&V2&" | "&$W$1&" "&W2)
```

---

**Note** that since you are using `Table Structured References` as per your given screenshot in the post, hence once you enter the formula in the first cell it will automatically fill down, also as there is no pointers when there is blank for cell values in column `W` what should be the output, therefore i have taken the return output for those cells shall remain blank as well. You may need to change the table name with the one you have in the formula.

---

> As per OP's Comment above:
>
> Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! I'll have
> to keep building upon this! If blank, I was just going to substitute
> it was "N/A". I'm assuming I can just add that in between the two
> quotation marks.

---

Updated formula:

```
=IF(
    [@[When should we follow up?]] =
        "",
    NA(),
    Questiontbl[[#Headers],[How should we follow up? (Select all that apply)]] &
        " " &
        [@[How should we follow up? (Select all that apply)]] &
        " | " &
        Questiontbl[[#Headers],[When should we follow up?]] &
        " " &
        [@[When should we follow up?]]
)
```

---

Or,

```
=IF(
    [@[When should we follow up?]] =
        "",
    NA(),
    $V$1 & " " & V3 & " | " &
        $W$1 & " " & W3
)
```

---

**Edit:**

OP updated post with newer question, which wasn't earlier

> Sorry, I was hoping to grasp the full concept of the formula. I've
> added another screenshot under my original post "enter image
> description here". These are all the Column Headers. It ends at Column
> AI. Do you know how I can build upon what you've built to extend all
> the way to Column AI? Thank you!

---

Using <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd> & <kbd>BYCOL( )</kbd> not referencing the **Structured references** specifically using the **Cell reference** to make the <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> work. Also not using <kbd>NA( )</kbd> function instead used `N/A` within speech marks.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>T2</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(
    " | " & CHAR(10),
    ,
    TRIM($U$1:$AI$1) & " " &
        BYCOL(
            U2:AI2,
            LAMBDA(α,
                IF(
                    α = "",
                    "N/A",
                    α
                )
            )
        )
)
```

---